# How do I prevent Boost.Interprocess from using wchar?

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

I'm trying to cross compile some Boost Interprocess code to an environment that doesn't have implementations for wchar functions such a wcslen, and wmemset.

Here's my code:

```
#define BOOST_NO_CWCHAR
#define BOOST_NO_CWCTYPE
#define BOOST_NO_CTYPE_FUNCTIONS
#define BOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_WCHAR_T
#define BOOST_NO_STD_WSTREAMBUF
#define BOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING
#define BOOST_NO_CHAR32_T
#define BOOST_NO_CHAR16_T
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR16_T
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR32_T
#define BOOST_NO_UNICODE_LITERALS

#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
//#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_PROCESS_SHARED
//#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_TIMEOUTS
//#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_HIGH_PRECISION_CLOCK
#define BOOST_HAS_GETTIMEOFDAY
#define CGAL_HAS_NO_THREADS -U__GNUG__
#define BOOST_NO_NATIVE_LONG_DOUBLE_FP_CLASSIFY
#define BOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS



#include <boost/interprocess/managed_external_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/aligned_storage.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

//Alias an integer node allocator type
//This allocator will allocate memory inside the static buffer
typedef allocator<int, wmanaged_external_buffer::segment_manager>
   allocator_t;

//Alias a STL compatible list to be constructed in the static buffer
typedef list<int, allocator_t>    MyBufferList;


void processWork(char *data, int size)
{
    const int localSize = 65536;
    static boost::aligned_storage<localSize>::type static_buffer2;
    std::memcpy(&static_buffer2, data, localSize);

    wmanaged_external_buffer objects_in_static_memory2
       (open_only, &static_buffer2, localSize);

    //Check that "MyList" has been duplicated in the second buffer
    MyBufferList *list = objects_in_static_memory2.find<MyBufferList>(L"MyList").first;
    std::cout << list->front();

    **objects_in_static_memory2.destroy<MyBufferList>(L"MyList");**

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting";

   //Create the static memory who will store all objects
   const int memsize = 65536;

   static boost::aligned_storage<memsize>::type static_buffer;

   //This managed memory will construct objects associated with
   //a wide string in the static buffer
   wmanaged_external_buffer objects_in_static_memory
      (create_only, &static_buffer, memsize);

   //We optimize resources to create 100 named objects in the static buffer
   objects_in_static_memory.reserve_named_objects(100);



   //The list must be initialized with the allocator
   //All objects created with objects_in_static_memory will
   //be stored in the static_buffer!
   MyBufferList *list = objects_in_static_memory.construct<MyBufferList>(L"MyList")
                           (objects_in_static_memory.get_segment_manager());


   list->push_back(624);
   processWork((char*)static_buffer.address(), memsize);
   objects_in_static_memory.destroy<MyBufferList>(L"MyList");

   return 0;
}
```

The calls with L"MyList" in them precipitate a call in boost /interprocess/segment_manager.cpp to:

```
 index_it it = index.find(key_type (name, std::char_traits<CharT>::length(name)));
```

And that tries to call wcslen in libcxx/string, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I tried removing the 'L' from the buffer name, but then it complains the argument is not wchar. Any guidance on how to remove this wchar dependency most appreciated - the macros I've set unfortunately don't seem to do the trick.

I'm using the latest Boost headers (not the ones on my system)

Marcos

Comment: Ahhh. That was it. Being a dufuss and using wmanaged_external_buffer instead of managed_external_buffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wmanaged_external_buffer` is a typedef for `basic_managed_external_buffer<wchar_t>`, just like `std::wstring` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`.

You should be using `managed_external_buffer` (or `basic_managed_external_buffer<char>` directly).

Comment: It was my fault for just copying and pasting the example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer.managed_external_buffer